# Which sentence is better to say which stamp I can take?

Tags: word-usage

Let’s say that my brother collects stamps and he wanted to me to take some stamps on one condition. Would it be correct if he said the sentences below to describe the condition:

> You can take one of some stamps which have two examples.
>
> You can take one of stamp of which there are two.

Especially is the word ”example” correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your first sentence is not clear; the second needs a minor correction.

If your brother says that you can **take one of some stamps**, it is not clear how many stamps he is talking about. To be clear, he should say:

> You can take one of (all) THOSE stamps of which I have duplicates.

Instead of **duplicates** you might also say **examples** or **copies**.

It would also be possible to say **You can take one of the stamps (plural) of which there are two**, which is very close to what you suggest.